# 'I know what is freedom / freedom is'. <-- Word order in WH-questions

Tags: syntactic-analysis, word-order, questions, subordinate-clauses, grammatical-roles

My understanding is that in a *wh-* subordinate clause, we must use statement word order (subject then verb) rather than question word order (verb then subject):

- Correct: *I know what freedom is.*
- Wrong: *I know what is freedom.*

So, why are Sentences 1–3 correct?

1. *I know who is coming.*
2. *I know which is better.*
3. *I know what is next.*

---

Also, possibly relevant:

For *when*, *why*, *whether*, *how*, and *if*, I can't seem to construct sentences similar to 1–3. That is, Sentence 4 doesn't seem to ever work:

4. *I know when/why/whether/how/if is ____.*

Why? (Why and how are *who*, *which*, and *what* different from *when*, *why*, *whether*, *how*, and *if*?)

Comment: Why isn't "who is coming" an example of subject-then-verb ordering? The subject "who" is before the verb "is."

Comment: @alphabet: I see, you're probably right. I hadn't thought of that. Perhaps you can expand your comment to an answer? // Also, in *I know what freedom is*, would *what* be the object (or maybe subject complement)?

Comment: None of your sentences are “verb then subject.” In your original example, the verb is *is*, *freedom* is the subject, and *what* is the complement; in the other three, the pronoun is the subject and *is* (actually, *is coming* for 1) is still the verb, placed after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Short answer (tl;dr)

In *I know [what freedom is]*, the interrogative phrase *what* occurs at the beginning of the subordinate clause because the grammar says the interrogative must be the first word <sup>1</sup>(or phrase) in the clause. The word  *freedom* is the Subject of the verb *BE* and therefore occurs directly before it. We thus get an item intervening between the *Wh*-word and the verb.

In clauses such as *I know [who is coming]*, the *who* is not only the interrogative word, but also the Subject of the verb *BE*. For this reason, the *wh*-word occurs directly before the verb. The word *coming* is the Complement of the verb *BE* and occurs after it.

<sup><sup>1</sup>For the remainder I use '*interrogative word*' as shorthand for '*interrogative word or phrase*'</sup>.

---

## The Full Story

> - Correct: *I know what freedom is.*
> - Wrong: *I know what is freedom.*

The Original Poster notes that the first example seems natural and the second less so. In actual fact the second example is grammatical but is a slightly different question, and a slightly unusual one. We'll set that aside here and ask instead why the first, natural, example is different from the Original poster's  other ones below:

1. *I know who is coming.*
2. *I know which is better.*
3. *I know what is next.*

The difficulty that arises with the original poster's example, and which doesn't apply to examples (1-3), is that the Original Poster's example has two noun phrases (NPs) joined by the verb *BE*. One of these is the Subject and the other is the Predicative Complement.

In a declarative clause it is easy to tell a Predicative Complement NP from a Subject one. The Subject comes first and the PC comes after the verb. Consider the following:

4. **Bob** is Hamlet
5. **The man with the hat** is Bob.

I have **bolded** the subjects in each case. The PC in (4) is *Hamlet*, in (5) it is *Bob*. The normal way to understand (4), is that the speaker is telling the listener what role Bob has in a play (*Hamlet* is a character from a Shakespeare play). The normal way to understand (5), if we were listening in, is that the listener can see the man with the hat but is unaware of his identity, or that they have heard of Bob, but don't know who he actually is.

Now, let's imagine we want to know who's playing the role of *Hamlet*, or what the identity of the man with the hat is. We could convert (4) and (5) into questions thus:

6. **Who** is Hamlet?
7. Who is **the man with the hat**?

Now if you look at (6) and (7), it would be easy to think they have the same structure. They both have *Who* as the initial question word, and the verb *BE* as a copular verb followed by another noun phrase. However, if you look at the **bolded** NPs, which are the Subjects of the two examples, you will see that the structure is actually very different, even though the two sentences look identical. The structure of (6) is: Subject, *BE*, PC. The structure of (7) is PC, *BE*, Subject.

The word order in (6) is the same as the word order in (4). When the *wh*-word in a question is the Subject of the clause, the word order remains the same. However, in (7), the *wh*-word, which appears at the front of the clause, is the Predicative Complement. When the initial *wh*-word is *not* the Subject (or part of it), we see Subject-auxiliary inversion, and the initial tensed verb must appear *before* the Subject. In (7), we see that not only has the PC *Who* moved to the front of the clause, but the verb *is* has moved to a position in front of the Subject, namely *the man with the hat*.

We can see, then, that the phrase order in such interrogative clauses where we see two NPs conjoined by *BE*, is highly ambiguous.

However, this is caused by Subject auxiliary inversion occurring in the example where the PC moves to the front of the clause. Subject-auxiliary inversion does not happen in subordinate interrogative clauses. In subordinate interrogative content clauses, the *wh*-word or phrase moves to the front of the clause, but the other phrases stay in the same positions they would have in a declarative one. Embedding (6) and (7) in  a larger clause will make the two structures clear again:

8. Do you know **who** is Hamlet?
9. Do you know who **the man with the hat** is?

We intuitively understand that *who* is the subject of (8) and *The man with the hat* the subject of (9) because the two phrases occur in their normal positions directly in front of the verb *BE*.

## The Original Poster's examples

In *I know [what freedom is]*, the word *freedom* occurs before the verb *BE* because it is the Subject of the clause. The Predicative Complement of the clause *what* appears at the front of the subordinate clause because it is an interrogative word.

In examples (1-3), the Subject of the verb *BE* is clearly the word *who*, as the phrases that follow are not NPs but verbs and adjectives and so forth. Also, they occur after the verb *BE*! The *Who* is at the front of the clause as much because it is the Subject as because it is the question word.

Lastly, the OP asks why they cannot construct questions like those shown in (1-3) with the interrogative words *when, where, why, whether* and  *if*. The answer is that it is impossible to do this with the interrogative words *whether* and *if* because these two words are both subordinators. They just sit at the front of the clause and tell you that it's a question. They can therefore never be the Subjects of the subordinate clauses they occur in front of. With the interrogative words *when*, *how* it is a different story. It is difficult to use them in clauses such as (1-3), but not impossible. This is because it difficult but not impossible to use them as Subjects. *When* is a temporal preposition (adverb in old-fashioned grammar) and *how* is either an adverb of degree or of manner. Both of these are difficult to use as subjects. But not impossible:

10. I know when is best to have the party.
11. I know how big a donation is required.

### *That's all folks!*

Comment: If you really want to nitpick: main clause interrogatives don't *always* have the interrogative phrase moved to the front: "And, if all three bolts failed simultaneously, the consequences would be *what*?" (CGEL gives a few examples of this.)

Comment: @alphabet +1  Yes, careless slip. Think it's fixed. That better?

Comment: Yep! I'd upvote your answer but I already did so anyway.

Comment: @alphabet Thanks for the upvote. But thanks even more for keeping my post on the straight and narrow :)

Comment: What about *why*? Is it possible to come up with a sentence similar to 10 and 11?

Comment: @user182601 I can't do it easily myself, but that doesn't mean it can't be done. So, in other words: I'm not sure.

Comment: In #11 (_I know how big a donation is required_), the subject of the subordinate clause is not _how_ but _how big a donation_. //Also, in informal settings, it's fairly common to use Sub-Aux inversion in subordinate interrogative clauses, although CGEL says "it is largely restricted (in Standard English) to constructions where questions are cited, as in _Easily the most popular question put to the PM was: Why are we buying New Zealand carpets for the new Parliament House?_"

Comment: @JK2 Yes, I put '*or phrase*' in there at the beginning hoping I wouldn't have to tediously repeat it every time! The structure is the same as OP's 1-3. // Yes, some elephants have three legs, but the generalisation that elephants have four legs is still appropriate to wheel out in most situations!